# In my scenario the HTML folder (report) are being stored with current date & time. Is there a way we can auto delete old html folders (reports)?

Tags: typescript, playwright

In my scenario the HTML folders (report) are being stored with current date & time. Is there a way we can auto delete old html folders (reports)? I am aware of overriding the already generated reports, but can we keep only last 24hrs run report and delete the rest?

Comment: There can be multiple reports.Which report are you using currently?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.